# Angularjs , How do i set the ng-model for the input to change Date and Time with auto-binding?

Tags: javascript, datetime, angularjs, jquery-ui-datepicker

How to set the ng-model for the input to change `Date and Time` with `auto-binding`?

> **Here's the Plunker** http://plnkr.co/edit/7kuvF6

I want to change the Date and Time in this case, but I don't know how to setup the `ng-model` for both input.

Thanks !

Comment: You should add relevant code samples in your question to make it self-contained.

Comment: coz I have no idea what to put inside XDD

Comment: You have plunk already, so you just need to copy relevant code from your plunk and paste here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way setup the `ng-model` for date and time:

In your html file:

```
<div ng-controller="date">
    DATE <input type="text" ng-model="date" jqdatepicker/><br />
    TIME <input type="text" ng-model="time" /><br />
    DateTTime: {{dateTtime}}<br />
</div>
```

In your directive:

```
myAPP.directive('jqdatepicker', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      element.datepicker({
        changeYear: "true",
        changeMonth: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        showOtherMonths: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
          scope.dateTtime = selectedDate + "T" + scope.time;
          scope.$apply();
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

I assume you want to keep the format `2013-10-01T00:00` or will receive the data from somewhere in this format.

More detail in the working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/P7BG6q?p=preview

Comment: Cool ! Thanks ! This is what I need ! And i almost forgot the $apply

Comment: if i want to use this jqdatepicker attribute for all the datepicker how can i do that?

Comment: @jos As you can see from the code, the `jqdatepicker` is just the name of the directive. Once you configure the directive, you can add it to template as attribute. More detail: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: i have two date picker elements with ng-modal='someobj.startdate' and other with ng-modal='anotheobj.enddate'. if i write a common directive for both its not working.

Comment: @jos It's hard to give more detail without snippet. However, your ng-model binding object should look like dateRangeOjb = {start: moment(startDate), end: moment(endDate)}. Then, you can access the ngModel and do whatever you want in common directive. It's good to take a look at `NgModelController`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Answer (score 1):

You can assign it to the model defined in the scope in the callback function of the datepicker. You also need `scope.$apply()` to trigger the digest since the assignment is outside the AngularJS's.

```
onClose: function (selectedDate) {
     scope.dateTtime = selectedDate;
     scope.$apply();
}
```